# Question about the proof that if $G$ is infinite and cyclic, $(G,\circ_G) \cong (\mathbb Z, \ +)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I wrote up a proof for this theorem, which I believe is correct (please let me know if it is not). Importantly, there is a question that I would like to ask regarding how I constructed this proof. Given the following information:

[image: Given information]

The proof is as follows:

$\phi (\circ_G (x^a,x^b))=\phi (x^{\ a\ +\ b})$ by definition of being cyclic,

where $x^a=x\circ_G x \circ_G x ...$ $a$ times and $x^b = x\circ_G x \circ_G x ...$ $b$ times

By definition of the map $\phi$,

$\phi (x^{a+b}) = a+b$ which can be equivalently written as $\phi (x^{a+b})=a \circ_\mathbb Z b$

where the composition rule " $\circ_\mathbb{ Z }$" just happens to be "additional on the real numbers"

note that $\phi(x^a) = a$ and $\phi (x^b)=b$ and therefore $\phi (x^a)+\phi(x^b)=a+b$

so we have $\phi (\circ_G (x^a,x^b)) = \circ_\mathbb Z(\phi (x^a),\phi(x^b))$, which is the definition of a homomorphism.

In order to show that a homomorphism is an isomorphism, we must demonstrate that it is surjective and injective:

For surjectivity: if $n \ \epsilon\  \mathbb Z$, then $x^n =n$ and, by definition of $gp(\{x\})$, $x^n \ \epsilon \ G$...i.e. for any arbitrary $n$ in the integers, there is a corresponding arbitrary $x^n$ in the group $G$...therefore surjective

For injectivity: if $\phi(x^a)=\phi(x^b)$, then $a=b$ and $a+ (-a) = b+(-a)$ and $0=b-a$, which means $b$ must equal $a$

This homomorphism is bijective and therefore it is an isomorphism.

My question is, what exactly is the "addition symbol" that I used in the first line of my proof? (Refer to the below picture, circled in **red**)

[image: Symbol notation inquiry]

This addition sign surely isn't the composition rule defined on $\mathbb Z$, is it? It's just a short hand way of writing $x^a \circ_G x^b$, right? I feel like I have seen this sort of shorthand notation before in several different proofs and its difficult for me to distinguish when these symbols are functioning as "shorthand symbols" versus when they are functioning as legitimate parts of the proof.

For example, it would be inappropriate if I rewrote this as:

$\phi(x^{a+b})=\phi(x^{a\  \circ_\mathbb Z \ b})$, correct?

Any clarification would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Let $G$ be a group. For any $x$ in $G$ and any natural number $a$, we can write $x^a$ as the product of $x$ with itself, $a$ times. We then need to prove a little proposition that says

$$
x^{a+b} = x^ax^b.
$$

Here the $+$ on the left hand side is, of course, ordinary addition of natural numbers.

You can prove this by counting the $x$s on both sides and convincing yourself it is true, but if it feels informal or circular to do this, you can also define the symbol $x^a$ by recursion and then prove the equality by induction (really two inductive arguments, first on $a$ and then on $b$) if you like.

Once you have this proven for natural numbers, it makes sense to define $x^{-n}$ to be $(x^n)^{-1}$ and $x^0 = 1_G$.

Comment: could also define $x^{-n}$ as $(x^{-1})^n,$ correct?

Answer (score 0):

In group theory, exponents are usually assumed to be integers, with the standard integer operations (as exponents, by definition, count things). So that's a regular addition, the one you learned about in elementary school.

Comment: I am confused by this. That makes me think that we are including on to the $G$ group, on top of its OWN composition rule $\circ_G$, the additional composition rule of $\circ_\mathbb Z$. Is a group allowed to have two composition rules?

Comment: @S.Cramer You're overthinking this. $x^a$ is shorthand for $x\circ x\circ\cdots\circ x$. That is it. No additional operation on $G$, only a way to save space and energy when writing. It just so happens that $x^a\circ x^b = x^{a+b}$, when we interpret $+$ as regular integer addition. It's proven by first lining up $a$ $x$'s as I did above (with $\circ$ between them), then lining up $b$ $x$'s next to them, and finally note that we do indeed have $a+b$ $x$'s in total.

Comment: I guess the point that I wanted to address is that this is strictly SHORTHAND. It just so happens that in this problem, the composition defined in group $\mathbb Z$ happens to be represented by the same symbol as this short hand. i.e. $\circ_\mathbb Z$ IS, coincidentally, also "$+$". Is that correct?

Comment: It starts out as strictly shorthand, but as it turns out that one can do arithmetic on it, it _becomes_ more than just shorthand. Yes, I suppose one really ought to prove once and for all that this does indeed give (something isomorphic to) the group of integers with standard addition. But it appears so naturally that I think dwelling _too_ much on it is counterproductive.